# sorting a list of string based on a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing the high-level job titles and their order. for example

```
{'ceo':0,'founder':1,'chairman':2}
```

I also have a list of job titles:

```
['ceo', 'manager','founder','partner', 'chairman']
```

what I want is this

```
['ceo','founder', 'chairman', 'manager','partner']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
order = {"ceo": 0, "founder": 1, "chairman": 2}
lst = ["ceo", "manager", "founder", "partner", "chairman"]

out = sorted(lst, key=lambda v: order.get(v, float("inf")))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
["ceo", "founder", "chairman", "manager", "partner"]
```